# How to export XML in progress?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am new to OpenEdge and I am trying to export initially two tables to XML file. My ultimate goal is to export the XML file as:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LAS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <LASRow>
  <temp_wonbr>wo01</temp_wonbr>
  <temp_id>01</temp_id>
  <Allocations>
    <AllocDetail>
        <Emplacement>SUP.TR</Emplacement>
        <Reference/>
        <NumLot>22045</NumLot>
        <Expire/>
        <Qalloc>1</Qalloc>
        <Message/>
    </AllocDetail>
    <AllocDetail>
        <Emplacement>SUP.TR</Emplacement>
        <Reference/>
        <NumLot>22046</NumLot>
        <Expire/>
        <Qalloc>1</Qalloc>
        <Message/>
    </AllocDetail>
    <Allocations>
</LASRow>
```

[enter image description here][1]

Thanks for your help!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yWOP.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a dataset you can export pretty much any XML (with some limitations, like not being able to create xml-comments).

You might have to fiddle around with replacing certain datatypes with characters to properly create empty tags (an empty or really ?-containing date will create another structure that you might not want).

This will get you started

```
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttLASRow NO-UNDO SERIALIZE-NAME "LASRow"
    FIELD temp_wonbr AS CHARACTER 
    FIELD temp_id    AS CHARACTER.

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttAllocations NO-UNDO SERIALIZE-NAME "Allocations"    
    FIELD parentid AS RECID SERIALIZE-HIDDEN. 
    
DEFINE TEMP-TABLE ttAllocDetails NO-UNDO SERIALIZE-NAME "AllocDetails"  
    FIELD parentId    AS RECID SERIALIZE-HIDDEN 
    FIELD Emplacement AS CHARACTER
    FIELD Reference   AS CHARACTER 
    FIELD NumLot      AS INTEGER
    FIELD ExpDat      AS CHARACTER SERIALIZE-NAME "Expire"
    FIELD Qalloc      AS INTEGER 
    FIELD msg         AS CHARACTER SERIALIZE-NAME "Message".

DEFINE DATASET dsLAS SERIALIZE-NAME "LAS" FOR ttLasRow, ttAllocations, ttAllocDetails
    PARENT-ID-RELATION FOR ttLasRow, ttAllocations PARENT-ID-FIELD parentId
    PARENT-ID-RELATION FOR ttAllocations, ttAllocDetails PARENT-ID-FIELD parentId
    .

CREATE ttLasRow.
ASSIGN ttLasRow.temp_wonbr = "wo01"
       ttLasRow.temp_id    = "01".
       
CREATE ttALlocations.      
ASSIGN ttAllocations.parentId = RECID(ttLasRow).

CREATE ttAllocDetails.
ASSIGN ttAllocDetails.parentid    = RECID(ttAllocations)
       ttAllocDetails.Emplacement = "SUP.TR"
       ttAllocDetails.NumLot      = 22045
       ttAllocDetails.Qalloc      = 1.

CREATE ttAllocDetails.
ASSIGN ttAllocDetails.parentid    = RECID(ttAllocations)
       ttAllocDetails.Emplacement = "SUP.TR"
       ttAllocDetails.NumLot      = 22046
       ttAllocDetails.Qalloc      = 1.      
       
       
DATASET dsLAS:WRITE-XML("file", "c:\temp\xml.xml").
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want by combining your temp-tables with relations in a dataset and using the write-xml method on your dataset:

```
define temp-table ttlas no-undo
  field temp_wonbr as char
  field temp_id as char
  .

define temp-table ttallocations no-undo
  field parent_id as recid serialize-hidden
  .

define temp-table ttallocdetails no-undo
  field parent_id       as recid serialize-hidden

  field Emplacement as char
  field Reference   as char
  field NumLot      as int 
  field lexpire     as char serialize-name 'Expire'
  field Qalloc      as int 
  field cmessage    as char serialize-name 'Message'
  .

define buffer bulas for ttlas serialize-name 'LASRow'.
define buffer buallocation for ttallocations serialize-name 'Allocations'.
define buffer budetail for ttallocdetails serialize-name 'AllocDetail'.

define dataset dslas serialize-name 'LAS'
  for bulas, buallocation, budetail
  parent-id-relation for bulas, buallocation parent-id-field parent_id
  parent-id-relation for buallocation, budetail parent-id-field parent_id
  .

create bulas.
assign
  bulas.temp_wonbr = 'wo01'
  bulas.temp_id = '01'
  .

create buallocation.
assign
  buallocation.parent_id = recid( bulas )
  .

create budetail.
assign 
  budetail.parent_id = recid( buallocation )
  budetail.emplacement = 'SUP.TR'
  budetail.numlot = 22045
  budetail.qalloc = 1
  .

create budetail.
assign 
  budetail.parent_id = recid( buallocation )
  budetail.emplacement = 'SUP.TR'
  budetail.numlot = 22046
  budetail.qalloc = 1
  .


def var lcxml as longchar no-undo.
dataset dslas:write-xml( 'longchar', lcxml, true, ?, ?, ?, true ).

message string( lcxml ).
```

See https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=603f5bda9585066c2197989a

Comment: The easiest option is if you can use the write-xml method on a dataset as described here. 
If you want more control over the output you can use a sax-writer https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-use-xml/page/SAX-writer-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

```
TEMP-TABLE ttTempTableName:WRITE-XML ("FILE", "c:\temp\filename.xml", TRUE, ?, ?).
```

Comment: Thanks!
But it does not show up in the desired format.